# Bot crash removeRole is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi guys after using the command !Tempmute (user) (time) (reason) a person gets mute normally but when his time runs out the bot just crashes. Thanks in advance for help to repair it.

**Crash:**

```
      tomute.id.removeRole(muterole.id);
                ^
TypeError: tomute.id.removeRole is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\bot.js:245:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

**Code:**

```
  if (command === `${prefix}tempmute`) {
    let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get((args[0])));
    if(!tomute) return message.reply("Nie moge znaleźć określonego użytkownika");
    if(tomute.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Ta osoba ma zbyt wysoką rangę lub nie masz permisji!");
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "muted");

    if(!muterole){
      try {
        muterole =  message.guild.createRole({
          name: "muted",
          color: "#0000000",
          permissions: []
        })
        message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
           channel.overwritePermissions(muterole,{
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
          });
        });
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
      }
    }

    let mutetime = args[1];
    if(!mutetime) return message.reply("Wprowadź czas na jaki ma byc zmutowana osoba")
    var match = /^(-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+) *(milliseconds?|msecs?|ms|seconds?|secs?|s|minutes?|mins?|m|hours?|hrs?|h|days?|d|weeks?|w|years?|yrs?|y)?$/i.exec(
      mutetime);
   if(!match)return;

    tomute.addRole(muterole.id);
    message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> został zmutowany na ${ms(ms(mutetime))}`);

    setTimeout(function(){
      tomute.id.removeRole(muterole.id);
      message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> został odmutowany!`);
    }, ms(mutetime));

    }
  }
```

Comment: Just remove the `id` property from `tomute`. So it should look like this.
`tomute.removeRole(muterole.id)`

Comment: Antony <3 Thanks now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Remove id from tomute. tomute.id is just a string